# javascript times sum not calculating after the .

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript so please go gentle lol

I have a function that times one field against another that the user inputs. My problem is if the number is being multiplied by 8.5 its not taking the .5 only the 8.

How would I go about being able to multiply the whole number including .5

heres my function so far:

```
function chech() {
    amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value) ;
    prev = parseInt(document.getElementById("previous").value) ;
    multi = amount * prev ;
    document.getElementById("return").value = multi ; 
}
```

Ive tried googling it for a while now and cant seem to find the correct solution.

Comment: You use `parseInt()`. What do you think `Int` stands for?

Comment: use parseFloat instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change parseInt to parseFloat

```
function chech() {
    amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value) ;
    prev = parseFloat(document.getElementById("previous").value) ;
    multi = amount * prev ;
    document.getElementById("return").value = multi ; 
}
```